# Is it appropiate to ask here questions that only appear if you don't own the published rules?

Tags: discussion

This post: [Is it possible to stuff a Bag of Holding inside another Bag of Holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84078/15211) made me ask, is it ok to ask questions here about specific rules, which are only unclear if you don't own the raw materials?

As the case OP is asking there is an explicit mentioned case in each description of the item I ever read.

So on the one hand asking about rules here just because you don't own the published material regarding it, seems to me like only adding noise, while on the other hand I could imagine that at some point this could even cause legal trouble, couldn't it?

So how to handle this kind of question, and in case some action is required, what is the border between on topic and off topic for that purpose?

Comment: related: [when are the rules clear enough...?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6215/23970)? (Maybe not intrinsically related to the issue of *this* meta, but related to the linked mainsite question that prompted this meta.)

Comment: Just to be clear for future readers, the 5e description of the *bag of holding* doesn't actually contain the information necessary to answer the question. You need to compile info from both the *bag*'s description and that of either the *handy haversack* or *portable hole* to get at the correct answer. In other words, one could read the *bag*'s entry and come away with exactly the question asked. (It turns out that the poster *didn't* read it, didn't even *have* it, but we only learned that later.)